# Save the multiply array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, save, nsuserdefaults

I am tried to add more than one array but it delete old and create new one. How can I add more / insert another array to UserDefaults? Here my code:

```
let foodArray = ["Title": String(fShop_TitleInput.text ?? ""), "QTY": String(fShop_QTYInput.text ?? ""), "Price": String(fShop_PriceInput.text ?? "")]
        fShop_UserDefault.set(foodArray, forKey: "FoodArraySave")
        let getFoodArray = fShop_UserDefault.object(forKey: "FoodArraySave")
        print(getFoodArray ?? "No Array")
```

This work fine, but will save only one array at time. Example, I create new array title will be TestOne. If I add new title will be TestTwo, the array erase TestOne. How can I solve it?

Comment: Well, a lot of the problem here is that you've confused the heck out of yourself by using the word array. You call your variable `foodArray`. You call your key `"FoodArraySave"`. You call your second variable `getFoodArray`. In your question you talk of "multiple array" and "more than one array" and "another array". But you know what? It's not an array. It's a dictionary. I suspect that what you want here is indeed an array — an array _of_ dictionaries, or even better, an array _of_ some custom struct with `title`, `qty`, and `price` properties. But you don't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As matt points out, your data is of type Dictionary, aka [String: Any]. Whenever you save it to UserDefaults, it gets overwritten, because you're writing to the same key. If you want to add more data to the same key, you'll have to convert your dictionary to an array of dictionaries: [[String: Any]]. Then you can access individual dictionaries by enumeration, or by accessing the particular index you're interested in.

The other way would be to save each piece of data in a different key, like "FoodArraySave1", "FoodArraySave2", "FoodArraySave3".  That's probably more involved and less efficient though.

This is probably what you want to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        var myFoodData: [[String: Any]] = []

        let foodArray: [String: Any] = ["Title": "Eggs", "QTY": 18, "Price": 5.50]
        let foodArray2: [String: Any] = ["Title": "Bacon", "QTY": 12, "Price": 12.50]

        myFoodData.append(foodArray)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myFoodData, forKey: "FoodArraySave")

        var getFoodData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "FoodArraySave") as! [[String: Any]]

        print(getFoodData[0])

        myFoodData.append((foodArray2))
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myFoodData, forKey: "FoodArraySave")

        getFoodData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "FoodArraySave") as! [[String: Any]]

        print(getFoodData[1])
    }
```

Comment: For almost three days of struggled until I finally got answered from you. It finally work. Thank you thank you.